# How to sync S3 and Wordpress folders with every upload?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Wordpress site which is fronted by AWS Cloudfront and the static files under **/wp-content** and **/wp-includes** are pointing to an S3 bucket.

What I do is every update on the site, I manually run this on the two folders:

```
aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket
```

This works well but I would like to automated it and I don't want to run a cronjob as it's ineffecient.

Any ideas on how to make this automated?

Thanks

Comment: Reviewing how plugins that do this may help get you started: https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/.

Comment: I had a look at this plugin and although it works for S3 directly, Cloudfront option is a paid feature. I just want to sync the folders with S3 every time a new file is dropped

Answer (score 0):

Try WP Offload Media Lite plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/

I have used it myself and it works well for the medial files, however if you want all your static content to be served from an S3 bucket then you will have to read this guide : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/best-practices-wordpress/welcome.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34752308)

Comment: I have tried this before too. This only allows one path to be in sync whereas in my set up, I will have various folders that will be offloaded to Cloudfront. Hence why the question is phrased that way.